# Overwrite a variable and stay with the value c#

Tags: c#, global-variables

How can I make a variable what is not initially defined (`string name = "";`) and when the user chooses a value (in this case the path of a directory), the value (path) is kept in memory, so doesn't need to be input again. This value should be stored, so that when my application is restarted, it is still available.

This is my global variable:

```
static class Global
{
    private static string path = "";

    public static string GlobalVar
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }
}
```

and this is my button action:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
        Global.GlobalVar = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I don't understand "once the program is published that variable save that value and did not put it beyond." - could you try and reword this?

Comment: Please don't downvote the OP due to poor english - lets wait to see if we can reword this first!

Comment: Excellent - thanks. And by "retained" do you mean whilst the program is running, or even after the program is restarted?

Comment: @ChrisBallard one time the program  run for first time, it need to remember the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "permanent global variable". Instead, use the builtin configuration mechanisms of the .NET framework.

In Visual Studio, open the project properties and navigate to the tab "Settings". There's now probably a link on the right pane saying that no default settings were created so far. Click the link to create the settings.

Then, add an new user setting by entering a name and selecting the type (string, int, etc.). Make sure it is a *user* setting, not an *application* setting, as application settings are read only. From then on, you can access this setting like a variable using `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`.

So save the setting permanently between program/machine restarts, use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResourceManager` to save your configurations and when you stop your program it will start loading settings correctly , like this:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("RootResourceName",
                                         typeof(SomeClass).Assembly);
string path = rm.GetString("path");
```

Comment: Why does everyone use `ResourceManager` instead of using `Properties.Settings`?

Answer (score -1):

You could update your `Global` class to ensure the value is stored in the Registry, under (eg) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, so:

```
public static class Global
{
    private static string path = "";

    public static string GlobalVar
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                path = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApplication", "DirectoryPath", String.Empty); 
            }
            return path; 
        }
        set
        {
            path = value;
            Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApplication", "DirectoryPath", path,
                                RegistryValueKind.String);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nooo! Don't use the Registry! .NET Applications come with a very handy configuration mechanism!! Stop polluting the Registry...

Comment: Each to his own :) - OP - you may want to check @ThorstenDittmar answer as well - that could be used with this same method, but using `Properties.Settings...` instead of the `Registry`